# dataframe not sorting by date

Tags: python, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, columnsorting

I have a dataframe which looks like:

`prediction = set(zip(future_forecast_dates[-120:], I, R))`

`prediction = pd.DataFrame(prediction)`

`prediction.columns = ['date', 'Infected', 'recovered']`

`print(prediction.head())`

OUTPUT -

[image]

I am trying to make a SIR model

and i am trying to sort this dataframe according to date using the following code:
 `prediction = prediction.sort_values(by=['date'],axis=1)`

but then again i get the error:

[image]

I am using jupyter notebook

Comment: Hi, please post your dataframe as text so we can help you better. Also, can you try to run those cells with restarting the kernel?

Comment: @IbrahimBerber hi i changed the dataframe as text but cant do it with the output, its looking like a mess.

Comment: I just asked you so because I could create a dataframe on my computer quickly, but it is OK. Did changing `axis=0` work?

Comment: @IbrahimBerber Yes it did thank you very much

Comment: You are very welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to change `axis=1` to `axis=0`.

```py
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1, 2, 3, 4],
                     "B": [11, 13, 17, 9]})

print(data.head())
   A   B
0  1  11
1  2  13
2  3  17
3  4   9


data = data.sort_values(by=['B'], axis=0)
print(data.head())
   A   B
3  4   9
0  1  11
1  2  13
2  3  17
```